# iOS - Why does this NSString comparison blow-up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, response

I have looked at SO for similar questions, but am open to being pointed to a duplicate.

I am receiving some JSON from a site, and I want to test for a 404 response.

I have this expression:

```
    NSString *responseString = [json objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
NSLog(@"responseString: %@", responseString);

        NSString *myString1 = @"404";

        NSLog(@"%d", (responseString == myString1)); //0
        NSLog(@"%d", [responseString isEqual:myString1]); //0
        NSLog(@"%d", [responseString isEqualToString:myString1]); //Crash
```

The response string returns 404.
The first and second logs result in 0, and the 3rd crashes with this log:

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000001943
2015-01-29 16:23:33.302 Metro[19057:5064427] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000001943'
```

Comment: Read the error. It's quite clear. `responseString` is an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that. But I call responseString as a string. Do I need to convert the contents too?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte: `[json objectForKey:@"statusCode"]` probably returns an instance of `NSNumber`, even if you call it an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statusCode` is a number, not a string. The error makes this clear by telling you that you are trying to call `isEqualToString` on an `NSNumber`.

Try this:

```
NSInteger responseCode = [json[@"statusCode"] integerValue];
NSInteger notFoundCode = 404;
if (responseCode == notFoundCode) {
    // process 404 error
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, seems obvious in the rear view mirror :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you declared  `responseString` as an `NSString` does not guarantee that `[json objectForKey:@"statusCode"]` will indeed return an `NSString` object.

Actually, the JSON parser detected an integer in your JSON data, and as such, returned an `NSNumber`. So you should be able to test it against a plain `404` literal using `integerValue` or, if you want to keep working with strings, will need to convert it first with `stringValue`.

Anyway, try this, it should return `1`:

```
    NSNumber *response = [json objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
    ...
    NSLog(@"%d", [response integerValue] == 404);
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is fine. The 1st sentence of the 2nd is fine. But the rest of the answer of completely untrue. You can't simply compare an `NSNumber` object to an integer value using `==`. And you shouldn't leave the variable type as `NSString`.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, I've posted the answer too quickly and made some changes to it to make it more correct.